# Cuadros de dialogo sin Tkinter en python

Tags: python

estoy haciendo un sistema de logeo simple y al poner algo incorrecto necesito un cuadro de dialogo, todo funciona pero atras del cuadro aparece una ventana default de Tkinter(mi login es por cmd al exportarse, no por ventanas), existe alguna forma de usar cuadros de dialogo de windows sin tkinter? esa es mi opcion pero si de plano no se puede y es la ultima opcion, como quito la ventana default de tkinter y cambiar el logo de la messagebox sin usar ventanas...(el icono de la pluma default que se quite o cambiarlo)

Answer (score 1):

Si tu aplicación va a correr sólo en windows, puedes importar la biblioteca `win32api` que te da acceso a funcionalidades específicas de Windows y su API, entre las que se encuentra la posibilidad de crear un `MessageBox()`:

```
import win32api
win32api.MessageBox(0, "Login incorrecto", "Error")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Ampliación

Para elegir el icono que se mostrará, el tipo de diálogo (cuántos botones tiene, por ejemplo) y otras muchas opciones, se le puede pasar un cuarto parámetro opcional que es una combinación de varias constantes. Por ejemplo la constante `0x30` indica que se desea el icono de peligro. La constante `0x01` indica que el diálogo debe mostrar dos botones, uno que pone "OK" y otro que pone "Cancel".

Las opciones pueden combinarse entre sí con el operador `|`, de modo que si queremos el icono de peligro y los botones "OK" y "Cancel" se pasaría como parámetro `0x30|0x01`

Todos estos números están documentados en la [documentación de la API de Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox). Esto no es cosa de Python, sino del propio Windows, por tanto la documentación es de Microsoft.

Para no tener que recordar los números, cada uno de ellos lleva asociada una constante. En Windows estas constantes están en un archivo `.h` para cuando se programa en C. En Python se tiene el módulo `win32con` que las declara. Usando estas constantes en vez de los "números mágicos" el cuarto parámetro a pasar sería `win32con.MB_OKCANCEL|win32con.MB_ICONWARNING`

La función retorna otro "número mágico" que depende de qué botón pulse el usuario. Estos valores retornados están documentados en la misma página antes enlazada y también tienen constantes predefinidas que los representan.

Un ejemplo que usa todo esto:

```
import win32api, win32con

respuesta = win32api.MessageBox(0, "El login es incorrecto", "Error",
                  win32con.MB_RETRYCANCEL|win32con.MB_ICONWARNING)
if respuesta == win32con.IDCANCEL:
   print("Ok. Adios")
   quit()
else:  # win32con.IDRETRY
   print("El usuario ha elegido reintentar")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en los programas de windows ya sean descargados o de windows suena el sonido de advertencia/info/error y el simbolo de el messagebox que necesito(pasa en tkinter), con la libreria puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Añade un cuarto parámetro de valor `0x30`

Comment: Hola, me funciona, en esta pagina(https://www.programmersought.com/article/6450314331/) dice varios ejemplos para el MessageBox, pero hay algunos que necesito extraer info de ellos(si le doy yes haga algo y no otra cosa, y asi con los que necesite extraer info), por ejemplo RETRYCANCEL, YESNO, etc. Cuando uso 0x30 no puedo usar yesno u otros, solo quiero el sonidito no en si el MB de alertar

Comment: ya descubri como hacer el sonido, pero como le cambio el icono de arriba a la izquierda pequeño al que yo quiera?(perdon si pregunto mucho pero me gusta que mis programas tengan detalle XD) [la pregunta sobre extraer info sigue en pie]

Comment: He ampliado la respuesta con lo que me preguntas. Respecto al cambio de icono de la esquina no sé muy bien a qué te refieres. A mi me sale sin icono, como se ve en la captura de pantalla. Supongo que en todo caso el icono que mostrará, si es que muestra alguno, sería el de la aplicación desde la cual es invocado (en tu caso el de Python, o el de la consola, o el de Tk). No sé cómo se cambiaría eso. Quizás algo de lo que pone [aqui](https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-set-window-icon-in-tkinter/) funcione si usas Tk.